# How to specifiy hive parameters in Apache Superset?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-superset

Does anybody know how to set hive parameters ( like SET = ) in superset.

I am trying to set tez queue, as I am receiving errors while submitting queries as :

hive error: ('Query error', 'Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask')

Someone suggested a solution here: https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/287

But this does not work ( at least in v0.36 )

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. While creating the data source in superset. In the *Extra* textbox, you can specify the hive parameters in JSON

```
{
    "metadata_params": {},
   "engine_params": {"connect_args":{
   "configuration": {
    "auth": "KERBEROS", 
    "kerberos_service_name": "hive",
    "hive.execution.engine": "tez",
    "tez.queue.name": "network-job",
    "mapred.reduce.tasks":"2",
    "tez.grouping.min-size":"1073741824",
    "tez.grouping.max-size":"1073741824",
}
}},
    "metadata_cache_timeout": {},
    "schemas_allowed_for_csv_upload": []
}
```